# How to get the value of style - "width" in percentage using ruby?

Tags: css, ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here i am getting the data_width as  "57px". But the value is in percentage(50%).. you can see the below code snippet.

Can anyone explain how to get the value in percentage? I tried searching but nothing helped yet.

**Ruby**:

```
data_width = find_element(css: 'div > div > div').css_value('width')
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="someclass" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 50%;">
    <div class="ProgressBar"></div>
    <span style="visibility:hidden">&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

Comment: get the parent width (`pw`), the element width (`ew`) and the percentage is equal to `100 * ew / pw`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using something like this:

```
data_width = find_element(css: 'div > div > div').attribute("style")
```

The outcome of that will be `width: 50%`. To get just the numbers you can use regex:

```
data_width.gsub(/[^\d]/, '')
```

And this will just give you `50`

Comment: Yes, it will return, but if the style attribute has more items in it it will fail. So i have used this below code to get it work...  element.attribute('style')).split(/;/)).map do |value|
return value[/\d+/] if value.include? 'width: '

Comment: oh awesome, that;s a cleaver way of doing it